# How to add margin to div

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="width: 500px;height:60px;margin: auto;">
       <div style="width: 300px;height:60px;background: red;float:left;"></div>
       <div style="width: 200px;height:60px;background: blue;float:right;">Some great text here</div>

</div>
```

How can I add a 20 pixel margin by CSS code in text? I tried

```
   padding-left: 20px;
```

but this will make the second block go down .

*P.S.* The `span` tag is not an option, and I don't want to create another class for only the text.

Comment: You could add `white-space: no-wrap` to keep the container on one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to both elements or the the parent element, you can even add it to your `body`.

`box-sizing` defines how the size of your elements is calculated.
`border-box` means, that the sum of content width, border-width and margin-/padding-width equals the defined `width`.
Using `content-box` instead means that `width` only defines the content width.

Comment: thank u very much 
p.swill confirm as an answer in 10 mins